# Android Studio: Calling Function (like checkSelfPermission) of MainActivity from another class

Tags: java, android

I have been using this function that I declared in MainActivity Class:

```
 public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("OK","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v("OK","Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

This I used to check storage permission but because main activity class code goes too much bigger. I decided to make a class and save this code in it to call it. So I made the class as follows:

```
package com.example.filechat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class READWRITEFILE extends AppCompatActivity{
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v("OK","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {

            Log.v("OK","Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

I added extends AppCompatActivity because it was not accepting checkSelfPermission function.
But still this function does not work when I call it from class and throughs error some thing like:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Context.checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Similarly there are other functions like getAssets() that use 'extends AppCompatActivity' but still does not work? Just new to Android and Java, please let me know were I lake in knowledge. Thanks.
Note: I have created class in separate file.

Comment: Try to use your READWRITEFILE class in this way:
class MainActivity extends READWRITEFILE { }

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("OK","Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {

                Log.v("OK","Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("TAG","Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() instead of checkSelfPermission().

Comment: I have created class in separate file so checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) will not work as it will ask for 'this' argument

Comment: You have to set context instead of 'this'.